# How to find out caller info?

Tags: windows, winapi

This will require some background. I am using Detours to intercept system calls. For those of who don't know what Detours is - it is a tool which redirects call to system functions to a detour function which allows us to do whatever we want to do before and after the actual system call is made. What I want to know is that if it is possible to find out somehow any info about the dll/module which has made this system call? Does any win32 api function help me do this?

Lets say traceapi.dll makes a system call to GetModuleFileNameW() inside kernel32.dll. Detour will intercept this call and redirect control to a detour function (say Mine_GetModuleFileNameW()). Now inside Mine_GetModuleFileNameW(), is it possible to find out that this call originated from traceapi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `ZwQuerySystemInformation`  with first argument `SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation`.
once you have the returned buf, typecast it to `PSYTSTEM+PROCESS_INFORMATION` and use its field to extract your info.

```
status = ZwQuerySystemInformation (
        SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation, buf, bufsize, NULL);

PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION proc_info = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION) buf;

proc_info->ProcessName, which is a UNICODE_STRING will give you the calling process name.
```

Please note that the structure and field I am talking about is not documented and might change in future release of windows. However, I am using it and it works fine on WIN XP and above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many stack frames will be on the stack that are owned by Detours code.  Easy to find out in the debugger, the odds are good that there are none.  That makes it easy, use the _ReturnAddress intrinsic to get the caller's address.  VirtualQuery() to get the base address, cast it to HMODULE and use GetModuleFileName().  Well, the non-detoured one :)

If there are Detours stack frames then it gets a lot harder.  StackWalk64() to skip them, perilous if there are FPO frames present.

Comment: I wrote the following code but I get garbage value as the module name. void func(void)
{
   char module_name[1024];
   
   MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 module_base_address;
   if (VirtualQuery(_ReturnAddress(),(PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)&module_base_address, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32)) < 0)
   {
    cout<<"Error in Virtual Query\n";
   }
   if(GetModuleFileName((HMODULE)module_base_address.BaseAddress,(LPWCH)module_name,1024) < 0 )
   {
    cout<<"Error in GetModuleFileName";
   }
   cout<<"Module Name :"<<module_name<<endl;
   
}

Comment: Don't cast the compile error away.  Declare module_name as a wchar_t[] so you don't get Chinese.  Or use GetModuleFileNameA().

Comment: Still nothing. Module name is not printed. void func(void)
{
   TCHAR module_name[4096];
   
   PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION module_base_address;
   
   printf("Return Address :%x\n",_ReturnAddress());
   
   module_base_address = (PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)malloc(sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));
   
   VirtualQuery(_ReturnAddress(),module_base_address, sizeof(module_base_address)); 
   
   printf("Base Address :%x\n",module_base_address->BaseAddress);
   
   GetModuleFileName((HMODULE)module_base_address->BaseAddress,module_name,4096); 

   std::wcout<<"Module name"<<module_name;
   
}

Comment: Check the function return values.  Call GetLastError() when you get FALSE.

Comment: Here is my output: Return Address :1319e3
Return from VirtualQuery() = 28
Error code = 0
Base Address :131000
Return from GetModuleFileName() = 0
Error code = 126
Module name :

Comment: When I run GetModuleFileName(NULL, module_name, 4096); I get the correct module name Module name :c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\sample\Debug\sample.exe